Find binary string where, for every entry, the vincinity contains many negated entries
Consider the following problem:
Given are parameters $r$ and $n$: The goal is to find a binary string s[1]...s[n] such that the following formula is maximized:
$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=-r}^r s[i] \oplus s[i+j]$, where i+j is only considered if $0 \leq i+j \leq n$ holds.
Informally speaking, we count for each entry s[i], the number of elements different than s[i] within distance r.
For sufficiently large $n$, i.e., when the entries close to the start and end of the string do not really matter, the best sequence i found was to have alternating blocks of length exactly $r-1$, i.e., for $r = 4$, we would have "111000111000111000111000": For example, the first zero would contribute 5, the second zero would contribute 6 etc. This construction results in an upper bound of $n\cdot (r+2)$ for the sum.
